# Getting error when retrieving images from other class library - Additional information: Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a simple app to test if I can get the images from a class library.
I created a windows app called "MainApp", under the mainapp, it has a Form1.cs.

I created a class library called "ImagesResources". under that class, I have a folder "Template/Client1" and "Template/Client2". The Client1 and Client2 are sub folders from Template.

Every subfolders have images on it with build action: Embedded resource.

I added the "ImagesResources" on the reference.

I've tried this one but In getting an error message.

Under Form1.cs, this is my snippet.

`Bitmap image1 = new Bitmap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ImagesResources.Template.Client1.001.PNG"));`

`Bitmap image2 = new Bitmap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ImagesResources.Template.Client2.001.PNG"));`

Im getting error message.

Additional information: Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream' . Did I missed something?

I tried putting images on the Resources. It worked fine. But I need to get the image as embedded.

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly?view=net-5.0) will give your exe assembly, not you class library. If you have any public type in ImagesResources, try `typeof(ImageResources.SomeType).Assembly` instead.

Comment: you can try to set images property called Copy to Output Directory to value Copy always. Because it's seems to me like you've added your images to the project but on the runtime the are not appear. Try to find if the images are sitting next to your running assembly(should be in bin/Debug/ folder)

Comment: @keipa I think you didn't understand the problem. It has nothing to do with copy to output directory.